# Does the log4j vunerability CVE-2021-44228 affect logstash-logback-encoder

Tags: log4j

I would like the find out if the log4j security vulnerability CVE-2021-44228 (https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) affects logstash-logback-encoder?

Answer (score 1):

### Warning:

Alster's answer is technically correct, but it may be misleading to some people!

---

logstash, logback, and slf4j *I think* all use log4j-core-1.x... this means they are not vulnerable to [CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046) ... [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) ... [CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105). See [Apache's Log4J security bulletin](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html).

**HOWEVER** logback usess Log4J version 1.x and Log4J version 1.2 **IS VULNERABLE** to [CVE-2019-17571](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571) and [CVE-2021-4104](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-4104) (keep reading for more info on these)

On the [SLF4J website](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html) that Alster linked, the creators say that logback is safe from [CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046) ... [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) ... [CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105) because it "does NOT offer a lookup mechanism at the message level". In other words, logback is not directly using the vulnerable JndiLookup.class file within Log4J...

HOWEVER (again), they do mention that Jndi lookup calls are possible from the logback config file. This is documented in [CVE-2021-42550](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-42550) with a severity score of CVSS 6.6. This severity is lower than the others because the exploit is harder to achieve for an attacker, thereby reducing the exposure... however the end result if an attacker were to be successful is the same: arbitrary remote code execution.

Additionally, the [SLF4J website](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html) fails to mention the CVE's that are independently associated with their Log4J 1.x dependency that I linked above ([CVE-2019-17571](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571) and [CVE-2021-4104](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-4104)). Those CVEs are not related to the JndiLookup.class file, so their statement "does NOT offer a lookup mechanism at the message level" is not a mitigation for these. They do actually talk about some of the details for [CVE-2021-4104](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-4104), but they do not reference the actual CVE documentation. They fail to mention altogether [CVE-2019-17571](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571).

---

### YOU STILL NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE

[CVE-2019-17571](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571) has a severity score of CVSS 9.8...
This is an arbitrary remote code execution vulnerability (JUST LIKE CVE-2021-44228 that you asked about in your question).

[CVE-2021-4104](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-4104) has a severity score of CVSS 8.1...
This is also an arbitrary remote code execution vulnerability and in the description of it in the official documentation is says "that result in remote code execution in a similar fashion to CVE-2021-44228".

[CVE-2021-42550](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-42550) has a severity score of CVSS 6.6...
It is *also* an arbitrary remote code execution vulnerability

CVE-2021-44228 (which is the one that doesn't affect you) has a severity score of CVSS 10.

---

### My recommendations

While it does seem *possible* to use logback safely if you smile at it just right and tweak 17 different configurations, and upgrade a package, and manually remove a class file from a jar... I do not feel comfortable giving you all of the specifics of that. While I have been trying to help people with the [CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046) ... [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) ... [CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105) Log4J 2.x vulnerabilities... this software you are asking about is a whole different level of complexity and I'm not confident I could steer you in the right direction via a 1-time post without me or you missing crucial steps.

This package depends on software that reached end of life in 2015. My recommendation is that it's time to bite the bullet and upgrade to something that isn't holding on by a thread. I know that isn't what you were hoping to hear... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Logback does NOT offer a lookup mechanism at the message level. Thus, it is deemed safe with respect to CVE-2021-44228.
[reference](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html)